# Length of the data to decrypt is invalid in md5 for C# Windows application

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting the decryption error "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid" on this line

```
byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length-1);
```

I am getting this encrypted value from SQL database and before showing it in grid view I want to decrypt the encrypted value(the value coming from the sqldb). The encryption process is doing well but the decryption process is causing this problem. As far as I can tell, I am passing the data correctly so I don't know where this error is coming from.

I am selecting options from a combobox and date time picker and I am using my own data access layer to connect.

My code is below:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RetrieveGrid(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);      
}

private void RetrieveGrid(int istatus)
{
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           IDBManager dbManager = new DBManager(DataProvider.SqlServer);
           //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstyring");
          dbManager.ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SQLCN"].ToString();

           dbManager.Open();
           dbManager.CreateParameters(2);
           dbManager.AddParameters(0, "@istatus", istatus);
           dbManager.AddParameters(1, "@date", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date);

           ds = dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "sp_Getdata");
           for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
           {
               string DecryptText = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][3].ToString().Trim();
               MessageBox.Show(DecryptText);
           //Here Call The DecryptionMethod
               string AfterDecrypText = Decrypt(DecryptText,true);
               MessageBox.Show(AfterDecrypText);
               ds.AcceptChanges();
           }
         dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
}

public static string Decrypt(string cipherString, bool useHashing)
{
          byte[] keyArray;
          byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString);
          System.Configuration.AppSettingsReader settingsReader = new AppSettingsReader();
          //Get your key from config file to open the lock!(string)settingsReader.GetValue("SecurityKey", typeof(String));
          string key = "Trms";

          if (useHashing)
          {
              MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
              keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
              hashmd5.Clear();
          }
          else
              keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

          TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
          tdes.Key = keyArray;
          tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
          tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
          ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();

          byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length-1);
          tdes.Clear();

          return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
}
```

Comment: AFAIK , MD5 is hashing Algorithm and is irreversible(cannot be decrypted to actual value back), so what exactly are you doing , encryption or hashing??

Comment: for decrypt the already encrypted value

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding strings as UTF-8 to get them as byte arrays, that is not a stable way of converting between byte arrays and strings. If you have a byte array, decode it using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` and then encode it using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`, you are not guaranteed to get an array with the same byte values.

Encoding only works the other way, i.e encoding a string using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and then decoding it using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` will produce the exact same string. You can only decode data that has been encoded before, if you try to decode any arbitrary bytes it might not be valid UTF-8.

If you want to store a byte array as a string value, you should use an encoding that is intended for that, for example base64.

Comment: Thnk u very much for ur kind reply

Comment: Thank u sir for clarity on this are post any example on this